# handling 900 000 items in a list "quickly" when needed to access it multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, optimization, large-data

I've got a use case where I'm pulling in "links" to files on a server file share.

I then need to run some regex checks on these links and break them out into specific pieces so I can sort them.

Once sorted I need to split the list among x amount of servers to start pulling them. The sorting is important as each split needs to be even.

```
 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_3.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_4.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz']

 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_1.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_2.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_3.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_4.tgz']
 
 ['/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_1.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_2.tgz']

 ['/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz']
 ['/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz']
 
 ['/local/custom_name_4/c_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_1.tgz']
 ['/local/custom_name/ac_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_2.tgz']
```

For example since there are 8 files in a_database and and 4 per name, then say 4 servers, I'd need one file from each path to go to each server.

What I did was look at each link and then break out the path into a dictionary where the first value is a unique id:

```
{'uid' : 'local_custom_name_a_database_database_name_56', 'link_list': [] }
```

Then after I go through the original list again and add any links that fit to the dict:

```
{'uid' : 'local_custom_name_a_database_database_name_56', 'link_list': [ 
'/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz', 
'/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_3.tgz', 
'/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_4.tgz',
'/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz'
]}
```

Then split the link_list among the servers.

All of this works as intended however the second part, where I compare the original link to the new dictionary uid and add the link to the list takes forever. With 10 000 items it takes a couple mins, but with 900 000 items, it looks like it'll take around 125 hours. which isn't ok.

The real data is more complicated and there's significant sorting going on, but that isn't the bottle neck. The bottleneck is where described. While the logic works I'm certain I'm not doing this in the most efficient way.

Any help is appreciated. Even just pointing me in the direction of a better way to handle this many items outside of native lists and lists of lists or dicts.

Comment: You can try doing both steps in 1 step, by iterating the original list in O(n) time. Iterate through original list, extract uid, check if uid exists in dictionary, if exists update dictionary in link list otherwise add key and initialise link list as empty.

Comment: I thought of that and maybe im wrong, but I get the UID of the item im processing and im adding the dict for that uid to a list with an empty link list as you mentioned. then eliminating duplicates at the end. then going thru again and adding each to the list. tmp_dict_list.append(uid_dict_with_empty_list).  IF I have to do another for d in tmp_dict_list just to see if the uid exists already.. isn't that just as slow? because tmp_dict_list will be massive by the end and each will have to iterate it to see if it exists. which i feel is what im already doing? no harm in trying it i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If performance is a concern, this type of data structure `{'uid' : 'local_custom_name_a_database_database_name_56', 'link_list': [] }` is going to be a problem. It's O(n) to find an element based on UID. Instead, you need a dictionary mapping the UID directly to the link list. This allows O(1) access. If needed, you can transform the data later.

I don't know the exact logic behind getting the UIDs, so I just have an example one:

```
l = [
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_3.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_4.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_1.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_2.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_3.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_4.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_1.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_2.tgz',
    '/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz',
    '/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name_4/c_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_1.tgz',
    '/local/custom_name/ac_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_2.tgz',
]

def getUid(s):
    return s[1:].rpartition("/")[0].rpartition("_")[0].replace("/", "_")

result = {}
for s in l:
    result.setdefault(getUid(s), []).append(s)

print(result)
{'local_custom_name_a_database_database_name_56': ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz',
  '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_3.tgz',
  '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_4.tgz',
  '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz'],
 'local_custom_name_a_database_database_name_655': ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_1.tgz',
  '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_2.tgz',
  '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_3.tgz',
  '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_4.tgz'],
 'local_custom_name_4_b_database_database_name_5242': ['/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_1.tgz',
  '/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_2.tgz'],
 'shared_custom_name_c_database_database_name_56': ['/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz',
  '/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz'],
 'local_custom_name_4_c_database_database_name_58': ['/local/custom_name_4/c_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_1.tgz'],
 'local_custom_name_ac_database_database_name_58': ['/local/custom_name/ac_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_2.tgz']}
```

Then, if needed:

```
transformed = [{"uid": k, "link_list": v} for k, v in result.items()]
print(transformed)
[{'uid': 'local_custom_name_a_database_database_name_56',
  'link_list': ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz',
   '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_3.tgz',
   '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_4.tgz',
   '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz']},
 {'uid': 'local_custom_name_a_database_database_name_655',
  'link_list': ['/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_1.tgz',
   '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_2.tgz',
   '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_3.tgz',
   '/local/custom_name/a_database/database_name_655_1118843/file_4.tgz']},
 {'uid': 'local_custom_name_4_b_database_database_name_5242',
  'link_list': ['/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_1.tgz',
   '/local/custom_name_4/b_database/database_name_5242_11132428843/file_2.tgz']},
 {'uid': 'shared_custom_name_c_database_database_name_56',
  'link_list': ['/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_1.tgz',
   '/shared/custom_name/c_database/database_name_56_1118843/file_2.tgz']},
 {'uid': 'local_custom_name_4_c_database_database_name_58',
  'link_list': ['/local/custom_name_4/c_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_1.tgz']},
 {'uid': 'local_custom_name_ac_database_database_name_58',
  'link_list': ['/local/custom_name/ac_database/database_name_58_1118843/file_2.tgz']}]
```

Comment: explanation makes  a lotta sense. gimme some time to adapt this logic and ill report back. thanks for the "transformed" portion as well. there are some other calculations I need to do from the original link list later so its nice to be able to access the data in there later. the original link list isnt as simple its actually a list of tuples, (link, size_in_bytes, bool1, bool2)